# Blockchain.info confirmation misunderstanding

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations

I have some misunderstanding regarding how confirmation work on blockchain.info. If we go to payment history we can see info about confirmation in two places. First in history of all transactions. Like this

[image]

And second place is on the transaction info page
[image]

Could someone explain me please what's the difference between this to fields?
Why in one place they show Pending status and zero confirmations while in the other one they show 230K confirmations?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you didn't black out the received time and included in blocks field in the image. Are you sure they are the same transaction? If yes, then probably 232181 confirmations refers to how many confirmations the input used for the transaction has and not the transaction itself. Can you share the txID or the uncensored image?

Comment: @Pedro I'm sure this is the same transaction. In my wallet all transactions look like this. A lot of confirmations in details, but zero in wallet history

Comment: @Pedro do you have confirmations in first screenshot in your wallet?

Comment: I never used blockchain.info but I suppose 232181 refers to how confirmations the input of the transaction you made had...

Comment: @Pedro could you please explain what does it mean? Maybe you have link to some information regarding this?

Comment: Would be easier to confirm it if you shared the txID. If you send money from A > B in block 1000, and try to send B > C at a blockchain height of 1500. While the B > C transaction is pending and has 0 confirmations, the input B has already 500 confirmations (1500 - 1000 = 500).

Comment: @Pedro oh, I got it. Thank you. So if I have enough blocks that has my transaction I can be sure that it is valid and confirmed? Okay, but what blockchain.info confirmations mean then

Comment: 0 confirmations means that the transaction is waiting to be included in a block by a miner, 1 confirmation means that the transaction was included the the last block of blockchain, 2 confirmations means that the transaction was in the second to last block of the blockchain, and so on...

Comment: @Pedro ok, lets take a look at this example tx https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/a2e4a1624eab2aff0c41a00e58eed94bb9aa4f5df19889aa1ef99d58f50426cb this is confirmed transaction. But! In the blockchain.info site on the wallet history tab I see Pending: 0/3 Confirmations. They explain it like this https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/217116406-Why-hasn-t-my-transaction-confirmed-yet-

Comment: Well, you can always try a bunch of blockchain explorers and see what they say about your transaction: https://www.smartbit.com.au/tx/a2e4a1624eab2aff0c41a00e58eed94bb9aa4f5df19889aa1ef99d58f50426cb , https://blockstream.info/tx/a2e4a1624eab2aff0c41a00e58eed94bb9aa4f5df19889aa1ef99d58f50426cb

if they all say 10+ confirmations but blockchain.info says 0, blockchain.info is wrong. Blockchain.info has been losing its reputation since 2011 from what I heard.

Comment: @Pedro oh I don't know that, what wallet do you think the best?

Comment: I never tried them but I think Bitgo is better, although less well known.